# How to watch a SQL Server transaction log?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I need to watch the SQL Server transaction log and execute some actions when specific changes happen.

Is this possible?

Using regular database triggers is not an option at the moment.

EDIT: The need is to watch table data changes, not structure.
So when some table gets insert, update or delete, some action must be done. The reason behind using transaction log is to easily add some functionality to a database without changing its structure.

Comment: Not really sure what you even mean by this. What are specific changes? Do you mean file growth events or are you hoping to capture statements being executed against the db? This question is very vague and needs detail / substance.

Comment: Could you please explain what you want from transaction log? To track specific change on DB-level is about triggers or CDC (change data capture)

Comment: @Igor I've edit the post. Basically I need to capture statements being executed against the db

Comment: AFAIK there is no way supported way to view the transaction log data or capture data being written to it.

Comment: By what you have said, Change -Data-Capture would seem to be a good fit; If you want to read the transaction log you could look into [fn_dblog()](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-take-advantage-of-sql-servers-transaction-log/) but I don't think it will give you what you might be expecting.

Comment: Transaction logs keep before- and after-snapshots of changed database pages, not the statements you mention you want to capture in your comment. Consider setting up tracing via [Extended Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server) if you need to capture actual SQL statements. Although it's probably not as lightweight as Microsoft implies, it's less impactful than SQL Profiler.